# angular synchronous http request

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, controller, synchronization, factory

I have "angular factory" and "angular controller".

When I calling in controller function, call from factory function. 
But controller function is not waiting response.

And this is my codes.

[factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoMdp.png)
[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ezxr.png)

```
$scope.deleteCountry = function (countryId, countryName, index) {
    alert(countryId + " " + countryName + " " + index);
    apiUrl = url + '/' + version + '/country';        
    $scope.hasDelete = CommonFactory.deleteEntById(apiUrl,countryName,countryId);       

    alert($scope.hasDelete);
    if ($scope.hasDelete == true) {
        $scope.dataList.splice(index, 1);
        ShowMessage('Hata', 'Silme işlemi başarılı', 1);
    }
    else {
        ShowMessage('Hata', 'Silme işlemi başarılı değil', -1);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can Implement Promise for this or also callback . According to your choice you can Implement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we know that `JavaScript's` default behavior is `Asynchronous`, hence whatever your code is executing , it will not wait for output. To solving your problem there is two way either implement `callback` pattern or implement `promise`. I will suggest you to implement promise . `Angular` have `$q` service , by using this we can solve this issue . So first Inject `$q` in common.factory .

In your common.factory we'll make some changes and  code will looks like this :-

```
common.factory('commonFactory',funtion($http,$q){

  //here your some code according to screenshot

  return{

    deleteEntById : function (url,name,id) { var deferred = $q.defer();
         $http.delete(url)
            .then(function (returnData) {
              //Here you will check true false
              if(returnData.status.data==-1)
              // promise is fulfilled
                deferred.resolve(true);

                else
                // promise is fulfilled
                deferred.resolve(false);


                return deferred.promise;
            }).catch(function(e) {
                // the following line rejects the promise 
                deferred.reject(e);

            }) ;
            // promise is returned
        return deferred.promise;

  }
  }
});
```

And in your Controller we'll make some changes

```
CommonFactory.deleteEntById(apiurl,countryName,countryId).then(function(response){

  //do rest all your code which is depended upon deleteEntById .

});
```

I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: $http itself send promise object

Comment: I am glad . It was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `CommonFactory.deleteEntById()` must have `return $http.delete();`

use `.then().catch()`;

```
CommonFactory.deleteEntById(apiUrl, countryName, countryId)
    .then(function(response) {
         console.log('delete success response:', response);
         $scope.dataList.splice(index, 1);
         ShowMessage('Hata', 'Silme işlemi başarılı', 1);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
         console.error('delete error response:', error);
         ShowMessage('Hata', 'Silme işlemi başarılı değil', -1);
    });
```